# Please tell me something about multithreading in c#

Tags: c#-2.0

In multithreading how many threads are active or running at a time?

Comment: As many as you have created and called `Start()` on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out :
[Multithreading by albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

You will find answers to all your questions and more. This is a very good tutorial about multithreading in .NET/C#